# How do you edit multiple drop down menus

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, menu, edit

I have a drop down menu that I can edit just fine;

```
        // Connect to Local Host
        @ $db=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root');
        if (!$db)    {  do_Warning(-1);  exit;  }

    // Connect to Database
        @ mysqli_select_db($db,'coshh');

 echo '<tr><td>Harmful effects:</td>
         <td><select name="Harmful_effects"><option></option>'; 

       /* Create SQL to extract effects options */ 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `lookup_harmful_to_reproductive_system` ORDER BY `id`"; 
       /* Perform SQL to get effects options */ 

      $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 

     /* Build dropdown list for each effects option found in result */ 
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
     { 
       echo '<OPTION value="'.$row['Harmful_effects'].'"'; 
       if ($Harmful_effects == $row['Harmful_effects']) 
       {
         echo ' selected';
       } 
     echo '>'.$row['Harmful_effects'].'</OPTION>'; 
     }  
   echo '</select></select></td>';
```

However, I've been asked to change it to a multiple option drop down menu, which I have done and it inserts multiple options into my MySQL database. The big problem I've encountered is that when you go to edit this multiple drop down menu it doesn't highlight the previously selected/entered data from the database. I've made a start but I'm really struggling to get me head around it;

```
echo '<tr><td>Harmful effects:</td>
   <td><select name="Harmful_effects[]" multiple="multiple" STYLE="width: 500px" size="0"><option></option>'; 

   /* Create SQL to extract effects options */ 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `lookup_harmful_to_reproductive_system` ORDER BY `id`";

   /* Perform SQL to get effects options */ 
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 

   /* Build dropdown list for each effects option found in result */ 
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
    { 
      echo '<OPTION value="'.$row['Harmful_effects'].'"'; 
     if ($Harmful_effects == $row['Harmful_effects']) 
    {
       echo ' selected';
   } echo '>'.$row['Harmful_effects'].'</OPTION>'; 
  }  echo '</select></select></td>';
```

Any suggestions/help will be much appreciated!

Comment: please don't use `@`, take a look at the cost of using `@` http://themessycode.blogspot.com/2013/08/cost-of-error-suppression-and-ignorance.html

Comment: What's the value of `$Harmful_effects`? And can you please show the outputted HTML.

Comment: check $Harmful_effects geting the value or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got some problems with `$Harmful_effects` and `$row['Harmful_effects']`. Probably it should be more something like:

```
if (in_array($row['harmful_effects'], $harmful_effects) {
  echo 'selected';
}
```

It depends on how you store the array of selected effects to the database and how you initialize the variable `$harmful_effects`.

Comment: Benny - I used the following to put $Harmful_effects into the db $Harmful_effects=implode(',',$_POST['Harmful_effects']);
$Harmful_effects=mysql_real_escape_string($Harmful_effects);

Comment: OK, then you should work using `explode(',', $harmful_effects);` when fetching from db to regain an array. Then you should have a variable containing all harmful effects and a variable containing the harmful effects assigned to the current row.
After that you can iterate over all harmful effects and work with `if (in_array($currentHarmfulEffect, $harmulEffectsOfRow) { ... `

Answer (score 0):

`$Harmful_effects` should be an array containing the saved results of the select control. then you can use the following test to accomplish your multi-select.

```
if (in_array($row['Harmful_effects'], $Harmful_effects)) {echo ' selected';}
```